# QiskitError: 'Sum of amplitudes-squared does not equal one.'

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, superposition

I'm coding a 429 element length string to compare to other same length strings, but I keep getting that error. I used `ljust` to fill the string to a 512 element length. I'm using 2 qubits for coding and 7 for indexing.

```
import numpy as np
from math import ceil, log2
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit.extensions import Initialize

bitstring = "ATGGTGCTGTCTGCGGCTGACAAGACCAACGTCAAGGGTGTCTTCTCCAAAATCGGTGGC\
CATGCTGAGGAGTATGGCGCCGAGACCCTGGAGAGGATGTTCATCGCCTACCCCCAGACC\
AAGACCTACTTCCCCCACTTTGACCTGCAGCACGGCTCTGCTCAGATCAAGGCCCATGGC\
AAGAAGGTGGCGGCTGCCCTAGTTGAAGCTGTCAACCACATCGATGACATTGCGGGTGCT\
CTCTCCAAGCTCAGTGACCTCCACGCCCAAAAGCTCCGTGTGGACCCTGTCAACTTCAAA\
TTCCTGGGCCACTGCTTCCTGGTGGTGGTTGCCATCCACCACCCCGCTGCCCTGACCCCA\
GAGGTCCACGCTTCCCTGGACAAGTTCATGTGCGCCGTGGGTGCTGTGCTGACTGCCAAG\
TACCGTTAG"
bitstring = bitstring.ljust(512, 'A')
bitstring_len = len(bitstring)
bitstring = bitstring.replace("A", "00")
bitstring = bitstring.replace("C", "01")
bitstring = bitstring.replace("G", "10")
bitstring = bitstring.replace("T", "11")
n = ceil(log2(len(bitstring))) + 1
amplitude = np.sqrt(1.0/2**(n-1))

desired_vector = np.array(list(bitstring))
desired_vector = [int(x) for x in desired_vector]
desired_vector = np.multiply(desired_vector,amplitude)
    
qr = QuantumRegister(n)
cr = ClassicalRegister(n)
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)

qc_init = QuantumCircuit(n) 
inverse_qc_init = QuantumCircuit(n)
```

In the last line I get the error
`QiskitError: 'Sum of amplitudes-squared does not equal one.'`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just normalized the state. Just divide the state by its norm. For example: `x = x/np.linalg.norm(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this row:

```
desired_vector = [int(x) for x in desired_vector]
```

You set the varibale `desired_vector` to be a vector with $1024$ entries of zeros and ones, something of the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\1 \\0 \\ \cdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

And then in the row after:

```
desired_vector = np.multiply(desired_vector,amplitude)
```

You are trying to normalize the vector by multiplying it with a normalization factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1024}}$. But this normzalization factor is erroneous in that case - It would have been OK if `desired_vector`‘s magnitude would have been $32 = \sqrt{1024}$ - Like in the case where all the $1024$ entries are $1$, for example.

A normalized version of a vector is a vector in the same "direction" but of magnitude $1$ - Given a vector $v$ of dimension $N$, its norm is $\lvert \lvert v \rvert \rvert = \sqrt{v_0^2 + v_1^2 + \cdots + v_{N-1}^2}$, and its normalized version is $\frac{v}{\lvert \lvert v \rvert \rvert}$.
A normalized version of a vector is not dividing a vector by its dimension (that's what the code above is doing).

As @KAJ226 mentioned - this issue can easily be solved using the `np.linalg.norm()` method - which calculates the norm for a given vector. Then we normalize by dividing the vector by its norm.

In your piece of code, replace this:

```
amplitude = np.sqrt(1.0/2**(n-1))
desired_vector = np.array(list(bitstring))
desired_vector = [int(x) for x in desired_vector]
desired_vector = np.multiply(desired_vector,amplitude)
```

with this:

```
desired_vector = np.array(list(bitstring))
desired_vector = [int(x) for x in desired_vector]
norm = np.linalg.norm(desired_vector)
desired_vector = desired_vector / norm
```

And now `desired_vector` is properly normalized. If you initialize a quantum circuit of $10$ qubits ($2^{10} = 1024$) with this vector, it should be fine. For 9 qubits you need a $512$-dimensional vector.

Comment: It's the entire code

Comment: It seems like it is not the entire code, but anyway I have modified my answer with a proper explanation.